# ASP.NET/VB: changing visibilty of panel inside formview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, visibility, formview

I have a panel inside a formview that is supposed to become visible when a checkbox (also inside the formview) is checked.  I am able to access the controls, but I'm not sure how to actually make it work.  This is my codebehind so far, I know it's not right, but it gives a basic idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
Protected Sub FormView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormView1.DataBound
    If FormView1.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Edit Then

        Dim checkGenEd As CheckBox = FormView1.FindControl("checkGenEd")
        Dim panelOutcome As Panel = FormView1.FindControl("panelOutcome")

        If checkGenEd.Checked = True Then
            panelOutcome.Visible = True
        Else
            panelOutcome.Visible = False
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear but if you want mean when you check / uncheck the checkbox, then you need to use OnCheckChanged event of your checkbox like:

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkGenEd" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# Eval("YourDBField") %>' OnCheckedChanged="checkGenEd_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />            
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField> 

    Protected Sub checkGenEd_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            Dim checkGenEd As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
            Dim panelOutcome As Panel = FormView1.FindControl("panelOutcome")

            If checkGenEd.Checked = True Then
                panelOutcome.Visible = True
            Else
                panelOutcome.Visible = False
           End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That would work if it was not inside the formview, but since it's inside of the formview, you can't access the OnCheckedChanged event from the codebehind.

Comment: Ideally it should work because that sample code I just grabbed from  a working GV ItemTemplate. Did you get any error(s)?

Comment: Oh wow it does work!  I had tried the same thing before, or at least what I thought was the same thing, and had gotten an error.  I'm not sure what's different about your code but it works... thanks!